# Trying to redirect stdout to a file

Tags: vbscript, stdout

I'd like to send the stdout to a logfile with a datestamp and location for each printer.

```
On Error resume Next 

Dim objNetwork, StdIn, StdOut

'Initialize the printer connections object
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")  
Set StdIn = WScript.StdIn
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut

'Connect each printer
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\server\pr01"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\server\pr02"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\server\pr03"

'Remove old printers
'objNetwork.RemoveWindowsPrinterConnection "\\old_server\printer_1"
'objNetwork.RemoveWindowsPrinterConnection "\\old_server\printer_2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it from within the script open a file instead of using `WScript.StdOut`:

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
...
Set StdOut = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt", 2, True)

...

StdOut.Close
```

Otherwise redirect the output created by the script to a file:

```
C:\>cscript //NoLogo script.vbs >C:\path\to\your.txt
```

---

Timestamps can be printed like this:

```
StdOut.WriteLine Now
```

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "location".