# List all the wifi around me

Tags: vbscript, scripting, command, wifi

I have barely started vbs so I am new. I need help trying to show all wifi networks available around me. I am trying to fit it all in one msgBox. Here is my code so far.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strCommand = "netsh wlan show network mode=bssid "
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(strCommand)

Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll()
Loop

 
Wscript.Echo strText
```

It works fine for me just I can't see all the wifi names in one msgbox. It gets cut in the middle. Also, please make sure the script is in vbscript. It can not be make in HTA. Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: I'd write the results to a text file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBScript - Capturing output from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920690/vbscript-capturing-output-from-stdout)

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you for your help but I don't want a hta. I need a vbs. Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to redirect stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18728464)

Comment: I am sorry but it still doesn't. I appreciate your effort, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I redirect my vbscript output to a file using batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496816)

Comment: If you are already capturing the output from `StdOut` and echoing out on the script just using a command line `> myfile.txt` should create and add the content of `StdOut` to the file. If this isn't what you are asking then please, explain what's different.

Comment: Thank you and this helps, thanks to your explanation. I am sorry but I have just started scripting few weeks ago.

Comment: @coder9927 If that is the case, how can you be certain that the duplicate doesn't answer your question? Basically, your script requires no alteration what so ever, you just call it from a batch file or the command line using the `> myfile.txt` to create and output the `StdOut` to the `myfile.txt` (or whatever you want to name it).

Comment: Because at first, I didn't know how to use it. But thanks to your explanation, the code got to my nugget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224693/discussion-between-coder9927-and-lankymart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that save the data results into text file instead of MsgBox :

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strCommand = "cmd /c netsh wlan show network mode=bssid>%Appdata%\BSSID.txt & start /MAX Notepad %Appdata%\BSSID.txt"
objShell.Run strCommand,0,True
```

---

**EDIT : 09/11/2020**

You can give a try for this vbscript :

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strCommand = "cmd /c netsh wlan show network mode=bssid>%Appdata%\BSSID.txt"
objShell.Run strCommand,0,True
ResultFile = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Appdata%\BSSID.txt")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ResultFile, ForReading)
strText  = ObjFile.ReadAll
arrLines = Split(strText,vbCrlf)

Set oReg = New RegExp
With oReg
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\r\n" 'vbCrLf
    lCount = .Execute(strText).Count + 1
End With

'WScript.Echo lCount

For i = 4 to lCount/2 + 2
    M1 = M1 + arrLines(i) & vbcrlf
Next
    
For i = lCount/2 + 2 to lCount - 1
    M2 = M2 + arrLines(i) & vbcrlf
Next

wscript.echo M1
wscript.echo M2
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion and a quick reply, but I want the users to see it all in one messege box. Even if you do one wifi name per msgBox using a loop or some thing, I am still ok.

Comment: Now that I got your suggestions, I feel pretty strong on the design but I still appreciate it if  someone can get me what I asked before. Thank you all.

Comment: @coder9927 Give a try for the second vbscript and tell me how it works on your side ?

Comment: That is exactly what I had tried and works too good. Thank you

Comment: There is a small problem but I think I can overcome it.

Comment: What's the little problem ?

Comment: There was one but I overcame it.

Comment: It used to put 2 ssid next to each other and then gave the info. For example, ssid 5 ssid5 "info"

Comment: I think I'll stick with your first code though. Thanks for everything.

Comment: The first answer is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496816/692942) from 5 years ago.